# Sequelize not ordering on subnested query

Tags: javascript, orm, sequelize.js

I am retrieving data from a nested model with many-to-many relation, ordered by a field in the intermediate table.

There are three models: `Projects`, `ProjectImages` and `Tags`.
`Projects` has its own `order` field, and has a one-to-many relationship with another model, `ProjectImages`. `ProjectImages` has a many to many relationship, with `Tags`. 
The intermediate table between `ProjectImages` and `Tags` is `ProjectImagesTags`, and it has an `order` field to sort the tags shown.

[image: Tables]

Deadly simple. The models in sequelize looks like this:

```
const Projects = sequelize.define('Projects',
    {
        order: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
        title: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
);
Projects.associate = function(models) {
    Projects.hasMany(models.ProjectImages);
};
const ProjectImages = sequelize.define('ProjectImages', {
        title: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
});
ProjectImages.associate = (models) => {
    ProjectImages.belongsToMany(models.Tags, {
        through: models.ProjectImagesTags,
    });
};
const Tags = sequelize.define('Tags',
    {
        name: { type: DataTypes.STRING },
    },
);
Tags.associate = function(models) {
    Tags.belongsToMany(models.ProjectImages, {
        through: models.ProjectImagesTags,
    });
};
const ProjectImagesTags = sequelize.define('ProjectImagesTags',
    {
        order: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        },
    },
);
```

Now if I query the data from `ProjectImages` I can order by `order` field in `ProjectImagesTags` intermediate table.

```
models.ProjectImages.findOne({
    where: { id: 1 },
    include: [
        {
            model: models.Tags,
        },
    ],
    order: [
        ['order', 'ASC'], 
        [models.Tags, models.ProjectImagesTags, 'order', 'ASC']
    ],
})
```

But if I query from `Projects`, including `ProjectImages` and trying to order from there with `[models.Tags, models.ProjectImagesTags, 'order', 'ASC']` as before, it won't work.

```
models.Projects.findOne({
    where: { id: 1 },
    include: [
        {
            model: models.ProjectImages,
            include: [
                {
                    model: models.Tags,
                },
            ],
            order: [[models.Tags, models.ProjectImagesTags, 'order', 'ASC']]
        },
        {
            model: models.Tags,
        },
    ],
    order: [
        ['order', 'ASC'], 
        [models.ProjectImages, 'order', 'asc']
    ],
})
```

Same behaviour with `findAll` or `findById`.

I tried every possible combination including literals, and the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html) are not very clear. If anyone has an idea about how to do this query I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `order` attribute is only valid at the top level (any sorting on the subquery is going to get lost).

```
order: [
    ['order', 'ASC'], 
    [models.ProjectImages, 'order', 'ASC'],
    [models.ProjectImages, models.Tags, models.ProjectImagesTags, 'order', 'ASC'],
],
```

Comment: Hm, I see… so I have to declare the orders at first level; and in the order declaration I have to refer to the first nested model as well as the second nested model, as well as the intermediate table. It works.